# Node.js router() usage confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

why we need to use for example `var route = Router();` since by default below simple example of express already fullful the usage of route :

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
app.get('/login',function(req,res,next){
//..something
});
```

Comment: Express [doc](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The express.Router class can be used to create modular mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

The following example creates a router as a module, loads a middleware in it, defines some routes, and mounts it on a path on the main app.

Create a router file named `birds.js` in the app directory, with the following content:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// middleware specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
  next();
});
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page');
});
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.send('About birds');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, load the router module in the app:

```
var birds = require('./birds');
...
app.use('/birds', birds);
```

The app will now be able to handle requests to /birds and /birds/about, along with calling the timeLog middleware specific to the route.

Comment: so example.com/birds/about will use router.get('/about') of bird.js?

Comment: Yes. With this routes can be defined in different files depending on functionality and finally required in main file.